# Can HTTP Cloud function and event-driven Cloud function access same collection in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an event-driven cloud function (written in Node.js) that creates `video` collection in Firestore whenever there are changes in Storage bucket. But when I tried to access the same data from a HTTP function, the API throws a 401 unauthorised error.

HTTP Function:

```
exports.getVideos = (req, res) => {
   db.collection('video').get().then(querySnapshot =>  {
        return res.status(200).json({
            videos: querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()),
            total: querySnapshot.size
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        functions.logger.error('Error getting video details: ', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error });
      });
  };
```

API Response: 401 Unauthorized

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>

<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
    <h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/video/get-videos</code>.</h2>
    <h2></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't see any issues on the code side, so I was wondering what's the root cause of this.

Comment: How do you call this HTTPS Cloud Function? Which URL? Also, can you share the entire code of your Cloud Function. We don't see any place where you use `functions.https` to create a function that handles HTTP events.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec This function is not using the Firebase SDK.  It's a normal GCP Cloud Function.

Comment: How do you know that this function is actually being invoked?  Do you have a log from Cloud Functions that proves that it was?  Are you certain that you made the function public so that it can be accessed from anywhere on the internet?  I don't think this has anything at all to do with Firestore - you can simply remove the query to do better debugging.

Comment: Yeah; I'm with Doug here. I suspect the issue might be with the "Web client talking to the Cloud Function" part of the call instead of the "Cloud Function talking to Firestore" part. Can you add some extra details around how you're calling it? Maybe just start by having your function return some hard-coded placeholder JSON.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for bringing that up. That's exactly what the issue was.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman Thanks for clarifying and helping me in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that different cloud functions are executed using different service accounts. And one of them has required IAM roles/permissions, and another - not.

Another option - can you check that all of that happens in one GCP project and both cloud functions are supposed to work with exactly one (and the same) firestore collection?